# Is it correct way to return value in PHP

Tags: php, function, if-statement, return-value

I have very basic question regarding return value of a function, and checking the variable value.

```
function test($var1, $var2){
    if ($var1 == $var2){
            $var3 = "abc";
            return $var3;
        }
    return false
}

$value = test($var1, $var2);

if ($value){
    echo "Value is".$value;  //should output abc.
} else {
    echo "Not equal";
}
```

1. Is it ok to either return a value or return false? For example I am not returning TRUE, it is ok?
2. When i call the function, i store the return value in a variable $value. How can i check the function did return the $var3? Which of the if condition should be used?
   `if (!empty($value))` or `if (isset($value))` or `if ($value)` or `if (value != false)`

Comment: `$var3 = "abc"; return $var3;` should be `return "abc";`

Comment: I suggest to have a look at functions like `strpos`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is common practice in PHP to return `FALSE` as an indicator of an error condition. *(What constitutes an error is your own decision and depends on what the function is supposed to do.)*

However, since PHP automatically casts values to Boolean that are of another type (like the empty string or `0`, which evaluate to `FALSE` as well), you should do an *explicit* check for `FALSE` like this:

```
if ($value !== FALSE) ...
```

---

As Felix Kling notes in the comments, this is called "strict comparison" (or "identity comparison"). It checks if a value is *identical* to `FALSE`, where as `!= FALSE`, `== FALSE` and `if ($value)` only check if a value could be *interpreted* as `FALSE`.

Comment: @Tomalak what about `if ($value)` will this work correctly if the function returns false value?

Comment: @sunjie: Yes, it will. But with your own sample function, you could do `test("", "")`. This will return `""`, but your `if ($value)` will go to the `else` branch (which is incorrect), while `if ($value === FALSE)` will not.

Comment: His function returns "abc", otherwise what you say is corrent. It's easier just to stick to strict comparison and always use it.. then the code clearly shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: @yi_H: Yes, but I prefer to explicitly check for the error condition (i.e. for `FALSE`) when the function uses this method to indicate an error.

Comment: @Tomalak: there is no 'but', that's exactly what I was saying. === and !== are the so called strict comparison operators.

Comment: @yi_H Yeah, I got you now. Misunderstanding on my end, sorry. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a PHP developer, but I don't think your first approach works.
There are other things than the boolean value false interpreted as false:

```
When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

* the boolean FALSE itself
* the integer 0 (zero)
* the float 0.0 (zero)
* the empty string, and the string "0"
* an array with zero elements
* an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
* the special type NULL (including unset variables)
* SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 1):

1. It's perfectly OK to return different data types.
2. If you want to check against false, use: if ($value !== false). If you get lost which condition to use, this will clarify it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `false`, so I would go with that check: `if ($value != false)`

Comment: This will fail. Try `("" != false)`.

Comment: In which case will that function return ""? Anyway, your observation is pertinent, it should be checked that datatype is logical too with !==

Answer (score 0):

```
$var3 = "abc";
return $var3;
```

That's pointless. You're `return`ing a *value*, not a variable. `return "abc";` is perfectly fine.

> Is it ok to either return a value or return false?

Yes, that's perfectly fine for a simple case such as this.

> How can i check the function did return the $var3?

As said above, the function returns the *value `"abc"`*, not `$var3`. You're saving it in a new variable `$value`. This variable is definitely *set* (you just created it right there), so there's no need for `isset` or `empty`. Just test whether its value is `true` or `false` (or whatever else you want to test for). So the way you're doing it in fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can return pretty much anything from the function, or you can just "return" without returning anything. In your example, you'll get a string or "false" in return.
2. To check for false you either do if (!$variable) or if ($variable===false). Zero will return true if you do "if ($variable==false)" due to auto casting of zero to false (and any other positive number to true). Three "===" makes sure it really is false and nothing else. The isset($var) checks for existance, not value - and is not applicable to your example since your function will return a value or "false" and thus always exists.

Comment: `(!$variable) === ($variable == false)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried to say, but I realize I was a bit unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only right answer here is: it depends.

I always ask myself this question when creating a function like this. To answer it, I analyze what the function *does*, instead of what it returns.

For instance, if I have a getter, I expect to get a value, or nothing. In this case I often return `null` when nothing is found/something went wrong. 
A test function like yours should return a boolean at all times, in my opinion. Returning a variable when you're checking for something to be true or false is semantically incorrect, I think.

Aside from the semantics: returning 0, false or null does not really matter when you're checking it with `if (test($var1, $var2))`, since it will all work the same. However, if you want some finer details, you want to do an identity check (`===`) rather than a equality check. In PHP this is sometimes the case, for instance [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) can return 0 or false, 0 being a match is found, and false is not. Therefore the following would fail:

```
// returns 0, which is casted to false, so the 'else' part is executed
if (strpos('a', 'abc')) { 
    // 'abc' contains 'a'
} else {
    // 'abc' does not contain 'a'
}
```

So, long story short: it depends...